# Show Class instead of ID (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, class, hide, show

```
<a href="#tab1">Tab1</a>
<div id="tab1">content</a>
...
var a = $(this).attr('href');
$(a).show();
```

This works but only if the container has an ID since the anchor link starts with "#", how do I make it work with a class, so that it recognized `<div class="tab1">content</a>`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a = $(this).attr('href');
$(a.replace('#','.')).show();
```

---

```
var a = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','.');
$(a).show();
```

Comment: Beat me to it, 2nd one is what I would do, elegant solution.

Comment: @Nimbuz, also, `this.href` is faster than `$(this).attr('href')`. just so you know. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
$('.' + a).show();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrW8d/).

If your a regex'r (I wouldn't use it here, however), you could use...

```
$(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '.');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTeQM/).