# href anchor tag /css selector issue with canvas class instead of id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am using sketch.js html canvas library to paint on multiple pages in my e-book.In my application e-book pages are loaded dynamically upon loading book. So i injected multiple canvas sheets in some pages where i am supposed to draw like this :

```
......//page content
$(pageContent).append('<canvas class="simple_sketch"  style="background: url(images/white.jpg);" width="400" height="600"></canvas>');
```

and then calling the sketch function using each loop

```
$('.simple_sketch').each(function() {
  $(this).sketch();
});
```

So far this works well, i can draw the painting on each page, but when i am trying to add tools (Marker size, colors, reset button), My href anchor tags does not work. My html mark up looks like this :

```
<div class="paint_tools">
  <a href="#simple_sketch" data-size="3"><img src="images/pen-medium.png" width="49" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#simple_sketch" data-size="5"><img src="images/pen-medium.png" width="49" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#simple_sketch" data-size="10"><img src="images/pen-large.png" width="49" alt=""></a>
  <a class="colors" href="#simple_sketch" data-color="#8f395b" style="background: #8f395b;"></a>
  <a class="colors" href="#simple_sketch" data-color="#c44f4f" style="background: #c44f4f;"></a>
  <a class="colors" href="#simple_sketch" data-color="#ff66a2" style="background: #ff66a2;"></a> style="background: #46a843;"></a>
</div>
```

and here i am replacing id's  '#' with class's  '.' as

```
$('.paint_tools a').attr('href').replace('#','.');
```

But seems it does not work, Can any one please point where i am missing to pick size and colors, Btw, i like to have only this as the only tool set for all canvases in book.

Any kind of help much appreciated, Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW i followed this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062499/show-class-instead-of-id-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: here is how i fixed it :

i found that no need to replace the # tags , So i removed that part and i just used the click handlers to update my marker size and color as like:

```
$(function() {
        $('.paint_tools a').on('click', function() {
            var a = $(this).data('size');
            $('.simple_sketch').each(function(){
            $(this).sketch().set('size',a);
            })
      });
    });

        $(function() {
        $('.paint_tools a').on('click', function() {
            var a = $(this).data('color');
            $('.simple_sketch').each(function(){
            $(this).sketch().set('color',a);
            })
      });
    });
```

Hope it helps someone using sketch Library like me.